# How to retrieve current logged in user for dynamic file name use in model

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm trying to set the current `'upload_to='` directory equal to the current logged-in user's username so that each file uploaded is saved into the user's own directory.

I have tried to follow the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) which looks similar to this...

```
from django.db import models


def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.id, filename)


class UploadReports(models.Model):
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path, null=True)
```

I have also tried to add `RequestMiddleware` to achieve this but it felt wrong as I was implementing it.

I want it to grab the current logged in user and use it in the directory path. The error that comes up is: `AttributeError at /stylist/
'UploadReports' object has no attribute 'user'`

Comment: I think the `instance` does not have a `user` object. Maybe you need a `user = models.ForeignKey()` field inside your model first.

Comment: That is correct. I added `user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)` and it was not working. Forgot to add the new field to the form. Is there a way to do this without adding the field to the form? I do not want the user to be able to select the who is uploading.

Also, it is quite odd that the documentation does not show user being needed as an attribute, yet it does not work without it.

Comment: you can `exclude` the field in the form and set the user in your `view` with `form.user=request.user`.

Comment: Thank you. I will add a detailed answer of how it was solved below.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:** The Django documentation does not specify a user needing to be added to the model - though it does expect one.

When it was done the model looked like this:

```
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    return 'uploads/{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.username, filename)


class UploadReports(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    xls = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
```

If you add the user here then **DO NOT FORGET** to add the user to the field of the form as such:

```
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UploadReports
        fields = ('xls', 'user')
```

Once you add the field to the form there becomes a new field in the template form with the list of possible users. As most people probably don't, I didn't want the form to include the user. Therefore, as `ilja` stated, you must `exclude` the form as such:

```
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UploadReports
        fields = ('xls', 'user')
        exclude = ('user', ) # make sure this is a tuple
```

Once the form is excluded it will go back to throwing the error that the user does not exist. So you need to add the user in the `post` method of the`views.py` as such:

```
class FileUploadView(View):
    form_class = DocumentForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    template_name = 'file_upload.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        upload_form = self.form_class()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'upload_form': upload_form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        upload_form = self.form_class(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if upload_form.is_valid():
            form_done = upload_form.save(commit=False) # save the form but don't commit
            form_done.user = self.request.user # request the user
            form_done.save() # finish saving the form
            return redirect(self.success_url)
        else:
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'upload_form': upload_form})
```

It is not an easy task but it is rewarding when it is done!