# instance.user.id inside user_directory_path

Tags: django, django-models

How to access and use the uploader's **user id** in a Django model? Specifically, an example [hereabout](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) on using instance.user.id in the upload path, results in an *AttributeError* simply because a *MyModel* object as the *instance* has no attribute *user*.

```
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.id, filename)
 
class MyModel(models.Model):
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
```

Edit: Although it is similar to the topic [How to retrieve current logged in user for dynamic file name use in model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56228581/how-to-retrieve-current-logged-in-user-for-dynamic-file-name-use-in-model/56229509), using other objects such as the http `request` are not applicable? I want the field to be set to **the logged-in user's id**, that have just uploaded the file.

Comment: Where does your `MyModel` make a link to the user model? It looks like there is simply no user, so in that case, it can not make use of that link.

Comment: Using other objects such as the http `request` are not applicable?

Comment: no, models are request-unaware. That is the idea behind the model-view-modelview architecture.